# jQuery: check if element has CSS attribute

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to check an elements parents and find the first one that has a CSS background set and then return that background value?

Something like:

```
var background = $('element').parents().has(css('background'));
```

UPDATE:
This is the code I'm now using:

```
jQuery.fn.getBg = function(){
    var newBackground = this.parents().filter(function() {
        return $(this).css('background-color').length > 0;
    }).eq(0).css('background-color');
    $(this).css('background-color',newBackground); console.log("new background is: "+newBackground);
};
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If it's not set, fetching it will yield an empty string. Hence

```
var bg = ('element').parents().filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('background').length > 0;
}).eq(0)
```

**EDIT**

Some research shows that `css('background')` will *always* yield an empty string, or `undefined`, depending on browser. `css('background-color')` will correctly return the color of the element at hand; but also different values for each browser, so it is troublesome to test (`transparent` in IE, `rgba(0,0,0,0)` in firefox/chrome, for instance, both being accurate ways of specifying transparent).

```
jQuery.fn.getBg = function() {
    return $(this).parents().filter(function() {
        // only checking for IE and Firefox/Chrome. add values as cross-browser compatibility is required
        var color = $(this).css('background-color');
        return color != 'transparent' && color != 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
    }).eq(0).css('background-color');
};
```

Comment: what exactly is 'x' doing in function(x)? is that a placeholder or is it actually being used for something?

Comment: Try this: if ('') alert("The empty string is true!"); -- also you can convert a "truthy" value to boolean with !!.

Comment: also, should '.length > 0' be '.length() > 0' ?

Comment: @adamyonk: you're right about `x`. slipped my mind there. the parameter being passed to the `filter` callback is actually a zero-based index, so that wouldn't have worked at all. as for length, no, it's a property, not a method. `length()` doesn't work on strings, nor does it on arrays, in javacript. it'd be needed in java, tho.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. but now when i try to actually set that background-color value, it's not working, because 'bg' is [object Object] . What do I have to do to be able to set what's returned as a background? Here's my code:

jQuery.fn.getBg = function(){
var newBackground = this.parents().filter(function() {
return $(this).css('background-color').length > 0;
}).eq(0);
this.css('background-color',newBackground);
};

Comment: ah, yes, your question specified finding the first parent that has a background set, not finding what said background was ;) `bg` is a reference to the element that has the background of interest, so you'll have to modify the last part to `eq(0).css('background');`

Comment: does this only work for the first parent? or does it supposed to go to the first parent WITH a background? i'm getting null if the FIRST parent doesn't have a background.

Comment: actually.. found out that if the FIRST parent ISN'T set, it returns a value of rgba(0,0,0,0)

Comment: you're right, turns out `background` is never the way to go, and `background-color` will give a different value for "transparent" depending on browser. check my updated answer.

Answer (score 10):

I believe the correct way to do this is to check the .length property.

In your case you'd want to loop through all of your elements and check for the first one that meets

```
.css('background').length != 0
```

Comment: @David's answer is better, as far as using as boolean rather than length, but had to +1 this to... first answer which will work and needs some rep points.

Comment: @Rabbott, i want to get length of elements which has particular css eg. display:flex; how can we do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('selector').parents().filter(function() { return !!$(this).css('background'); });
```

Comment: An empty string is false in Javascript, you know.

Comment: @gaby oh I see what you meant Gaby; never mind!  And thanks for the vote!

Answer (score 2):

I'd try something like this:

```
var background = 0;
$('element').parents().each(function() {
  if (!background && ((e = $(this).css('background')).length > 0)) background = e;
});
```

Not sure if this exact if-clause works, but the each() should do the trick. The first match will fill the background variable and ignore the rest of the parents while traversing up in the chain.

**Edit:** Amended to resolve `css('background')` correctly which may emit an empty string. Additionally, `each()` does not pass the element, but index and element, thus make use of `this` instead and discard all parameters.

Answer (score 1):

## Retrieve element background color or gradient

I came across this as I was trying to apply a background to elements that didn't have one (background gradient or color) already.

This function returns the value of the background gradient or background color if it has one and returns false if it doesn't:

```
jQuery.fn.getBg = function() {
  var color = $(this).css('background-color');
  var image = $(this).css('background-image');

  if (color != 'transparent' && color != 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)') {
    return color;
  }
  if (image != 'none') {
    return image;
  }
  return false;
};
```

Now if you simply want to test if an element has a background, you can do this using the above function:

```
var curBack = $(this).getBg();
if (curBack) { /* Element has a background */  }
else { /* Element doesn't have a background */ }
```

Hopefully this is somewhat resourceful for someone working with gradients.

Answer (score -6):

You could do something like:

```
$('#test').parents().has(css('background')).filter(':first');
```

Hope it helps : )

Comment: css is not a function out of the jQuery context.

Comment: Agree with derrick, on top of that the .has() function takes an element selector as a its param.