# Jquery - select all anchor tags with display:block

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I can't get my head around how to do this?

Given a page full of anchor tags, I only want to select those elements with the CSS property `display:block`.

I think I can do it with a jQuery loop *(warning pseudo code!)*

```
var myarray;
$('a').each(function(arg1, arg2) { 
    if ($(arg2).css('display')=='block')
    myarray.push(arg2);
}
```

But isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: check if element has CSS attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239567/jquery-check-if-element-has-css-attribute)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with a function as the parameter.

```
$('a').filter(function (index) {
                  return $(this).css("display") === "block";
              })
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this would be to use jQuery's attribute selector:

```
$("a[style$='display: block;']")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have it as a jquery tool (if you use it very often). You can extend the ":" selector by adding the following code to your project:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    "block": function(a, i, m) {
        return $(a).css("display") == "block";
    }
});
```

and then you can select all block anchors by saying this:

```
var res = $("a:block");
```

see example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zFatd/7/

[NOTE] as you can see in the example if you use ":block" on a naturally block element (i.e. div) it will still returns true. (in other words "div:block" is true unless you specifically give it something other than block)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the display property is set by having a certain class or other property. This should make the selection simpler by using that attribute. Also, if ther other anchors are hidden, you can display the visible ones using the `$('a:visible')` selector.

Answer (score 0):

Or more simple:

```
$("a:visible")
```

Answer (score -1):

//hide all items with css display as block (slow):

```
$('*').filter(function(index) {
  return $(this).css('display')=='block';
}).hide();
```

Comment: This is the same as Joseph's, except the selector is not as per question, plus its hiding those elements which also was no per question.