# determine whether elements are visible

Tags: jquery

I have many `<div>` elements with the same class name that do not have the same parent.
How can I use jQuery to determine whether any of the `<div>` elements have `display:block` set?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery - select all anchor tags with display:block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637551/jquery-select-all-anchor-tags-with-displayblock). Also see [select elements using display:block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398444/select-elements-using-displayblock)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(".my-class", function(a, b) {
  if (this.style.display == "block") {
    return this
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume you're trying find `divs` with class `test` that have their `display` set to `block`

`$(".test:visible")`

This will give you the desired result

Comment: Doesn't this return elements that have `display: table`,  `display: inline-block`, or any other `display` value for that matter (other than `hidden`) ?

Comment: It does. :) However, if the code is following proper design then `.test` should only be having `display:block;`

Comment: Well, that's a big assumption: that 'proper design' would only have `display:block` -really? - there are many *correct* designs with other types of display attributes (all of them valid!)  You cannot assume that only `display:block` will be used

Comment: Okay. Tell me what `proper design` will have different values for `display` property on the SAME CLASS? Of course ONLY `display:block;` won't be used. However, if you change the value for `display` on the same class then you're doing something spooky. It is good to assume that one class should only have one value for display property.

Comment: I did not mean 'many' attributes for the same `display` property.  I meant that `display` property can have different values (other than `block`) and any one of those values could be used.  You are assuming that `visible` is equivalent to `block` (which is obviously not).  A `visible` element could have the `display` attribute set to something else (like `inline-block` or `table-cell`) - my point being that your answer, will select all the `visible` elements and not ***only*** the ones the OP is asking for.  It has nothing to do with proper design, your answer simply is not good enough

Comment: All of this nonsense could have easily been avoided if you had read the very first line in the answer. And no, it will NOT select all the `:visible` elements because the we're using `.test:visible` and assumption is stated right in the beginning that the `.test` will have it's display set to `block`.

Comment: but then you go an add 'This will give you the desired result' which is why I posted my question.  No, your answer will not give the OP the desired result, only the result in your assumption... You may think this is non-sense but a poor answer does not help anyone.  I was trying to verify the understanding (asking a question) and you gave me some 'proper design' BS reply - I'm done here