# jQuery check if .css property was set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My code looks like this

```
if($(element).css("background-color") == null){
  $(element).css("background-color", "white");
}
```

I want to make sure that if the color wasn't set in the `style.css` file, I add it. But that code is not working. It's always returning `rgba(0,0,0,0)`. The browser I am working with is  Chrome.

Is there another way to check if the color wasn't set?

Comment: Do your logic with classes and the styling in CSS. Then you can check if the class exists with `hasClass`.

Comment: that's one way. thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

CSS:

```
.background-set { background-color: white; }
```

jQuery:

```
var $el = $(element);

if( !$el.hasClass('background-set') ){
   $el.addClass('background-set');
}
```

Though I'm not sure why you'd need to check.  You can just add it without the condition.

---

Alternatively:

```
if ( $el.prop('style').backgroundColor == '' ) {
   ... 
}
```

or

```
if ( $el.get(0).style.backgroundColor == '' ) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method suggested by elclanrs is the most elegant way of handling this and should be the preferred method. However, for the sake of sating curiosity, you could achieve the same result using a [jQuery Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).

```
$("div[style*='background-color']").text("I have a background color!");
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gYxLv/)

Comment: Whilst this is good, but it only checks for in-line styling I think?

Comment: You're right, which is yet another reason why you shouldn't really do this when you have other options. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2239605/1351133 is a better/more thorough solution to this than what I posted.

Comment: Good link there, very relevant to the OP's requirements =) (Even if the class route is undoubtedly the best method!)