# How to access inline css style atribute and change proprties in DOM using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I need to change the DOM dynamically. I want to access the 'text-align' and the 'line-height' properties.

for example:

```
<p style="line-height:1.0;text-align:justify;">
```

I need to access all the style attributes in the DOM and go through each 'text-align' and 'line-height' properties and change their values. How to access these properties. 
Actually what I need to do is go through these two properties and change the text-align to left and change the line-height to 1.5 if it's less than 1.5

Thank you so much inadvance.

Comment: Is this what you mean: `$("SELECTOR").css('PROPERTY');` ?

Comment: As this style attribute can be anywhere, I need to go through all the style attributes and then should be able to access the two properties

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$("#selector").css({'property' : 'value'});`

from the docs : http://api.jquery.com/css/

You can set properties using this method.

Edit :
to check if an element has a css style, you can use the following SO answer :
[jQuery: check if element has CSS attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239567/jquery-check-if-element-has-css-attribute)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.css` method to achieve this:

```
$('p').css({'lineHeight':'1.0','textAlign':'right'})
```

**Update**:

If you want to select all elements that has `line-height` style you can use following selector:

```
$('*[style*="line-height"]').css({'lineHeight':'1.5'})
```

Comment: since the style attribute can be anywahere (inside a <p> tag or somewhere else) in that case I cant check for all the tags. so is there anyway I can access all the style attributes ans then check for the two properties?

Comment: @user3547920 Yes, you can select all element that have `line-height` style like using this selector: `'*[style*="line-height"]'`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("*").each(function(){
alert($(this).css('lineHeight'));
if($(this).css('lineHeight')){
$(this).css({'lineHeight':'1.0'});
}
if($(this).css('textAlign')){
    $(this).css({'textAlign':'right'});
}
});
});
```

Here `$("*")` will select all elements in `DOM` and then `.css("propName")` will check whether the `propName` property exists in that `element`'s `css`. and if it exists then `.css({'propname':'newValue'});` will assign a new value to that property.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I need to get the excisting lineheight value and check wether it's less than 1.5 if so replace it with 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, you can use:

```
$('p').css({'lineHeight':'1.0','textAlign':'right'});
```

You can also use:

```
$('p').css('lineHeight', '1.0');
$('p').css('textAlign', 'right');
```

Although not recommended, because this would replace all other styles, you could even do:

```
$('p').attr('style', 'lineHeight: 1.0; textAlign: right;');
```

To select all elements on the dom, just use the `$('*')` selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("*").each(function(){
        // 1.0 == 16px | 1.5 == 24px
        if(parseInt($(this).css('lineHeight'), 10) < 24){
            $(this).css({'lineHeight':'1.5'});
        }
    });
});
```

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/6RCRN/) is the JSFiddle

Comment: Thank you. I need to get the excisting lineheight value and check wether it's less than 1.5 if so replace it with 1.5.

Comment: @user3547920 see if this helps