# How can I check a parent element for css styles?

Tags: javascript, css

I need to detect if my parent has these css styles applied:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

I found [a jQuery example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239567/jquery-check-if-element-has-css-attribute) but (a) I don't use jQuery, and (b) I don't understand the complete answer.

Comment: `parent.style.display == "flex";`  where parent stands for you parent.

Comment: it won't work as it reads only css set by `style` attribute

Comment: try with `filter()` http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: As far as I know you can't do this with pure css. I guess the easiest would be with jQuery. Something like this: `$( "some_jquery_element" ).parent().hasClass('someClass');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [window.getComputedStyle(element)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and test your properties for default values, for example:

```
var element = document.getElementById("example");
var styles = window.getComputedStyle(element);

if(styles.getPropertyValue("display") === "flex"){
    // element style display is flex
}
```

Comment: Try this OP. This is correct. But pwolaq, If you don't mind. Give OP example to enlighten OP. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

You can find out using filter in JQuery.

```
$("#Myelement").parents()
    .filter(function() { 
        return $(this).css("myCssItem") == "myCssValue"; 
    }).first();
```

Comment: this is very inefficient solution